# iOS 9 constraint error

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

This code:

```
[self.collectionView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints: NO];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.collectionView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.topLayoutGuide
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                     multiplier:1.0f
                                                       constant:1.0f]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.collectionView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.bottomLayoutGuide
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                     multiplier:1.0f 
                                                       constant:0.f]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.collectionView 
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading 
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual 
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                     multiplier:1.0f
                                                       constant:0.0f]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.collectionView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing 
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual 
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                     multiplier:1.0f 
                                                       constant:0.0f]];
```

Work's fine on iOS 8 and iOS7 but now when with iOS9 when I run my app I get this error :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:]: A constraint cannot be made between a leading/trailing attribute and a right/left attribute. Use leading/trailing for both or neither.'

When I remove those constraints my app works fine. So I need to know what's the problem and what have been changed from iOS8 to iOS9.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your log clearly suggest that...either you can use `leading/trailing` or `right/left` not both ...

So just change 4th constraint like below

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.collectionView
                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing 
                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual 
                                                     toItem:self.view
                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                 multiplier:1.0f 
                                                   constant:0.0f]];
```

Comment: Thank's this solved my issue but can you explain me why in iOS8 it work fine bunt not in iOS9 what have been changed ?

Comment: @Chlebta Better parameter checking.

Answer (score 2):

I had these lines:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *leftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                  relatedBy:0
                                                                     toItem:self.view
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                                 multiplier:1.0
                                                                   constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:leftConstraint];

NSLayoutConstraint *rightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                                   relatedBy:0
                                                                      toItem:self.view
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                                  multiplier:1.0
                                                                    constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:rightConstraint];
```

I changed to this:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *leftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                  relatedBy:0
                                                                     toItem:self.view
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                 multiplier:1.0
                                                                   constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:leftConstraint];

NSLayoutConstraint *rightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.contentView
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                                   relatedBy:0
                                                                      toItem:self.view
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                                  multiplier:1.0
                                                                    constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:rightConstraint];
```

This is the solution to the error.